# Basics with DHT11

Tags: sensors, wires, temperature-sensor

I just bought the sensor [DHT11](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-dht11-temperature-and-relative-humidity-sensor-module-for-arduino.html) and trying to test it with the library code provided by the IDE, but I always get the same error on `.read()` . Code -2

```
/*####################################################################
FILE: dht11_functions.pde - DHT11 Usage Demo.
VERSION: 2S0A

PURPOSE: Measure and return temperature & Humidity. Additionally provides conversions.

LICENSE: GPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
GET UPDATES: https://www.virtuabotix.com/

  --##--##--##--##--##--##--##--##--##--##--
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  | ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ## |
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  | ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ## |
  ##  ##  ##  ## DHT11 SENSOR ##  ##  ##  ##
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##FRONT ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  | ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ## |
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  | ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ## |
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
  --##--##--##--##--##--##--##--##--##--##--
      ||       ||          || (Not    ||
      ||       ||          || Used)   ||
    VDD(5V)   Readout(I/O)          Ground

HISTORY:
Joseph Dattilo (Virtuabotix LLC) - Version 2S0A (27 May 12)
-Rewritten to with more powerful Versalino functionality
Joseph Dattilo (Virtuabotix LLC) - Version 0.4.5 (11/11/11)
-Made Library Arduino 1.0 Compatible
Joseph Dattilo (Virtuabotix LLC) - Version 0.4.0 (06/11/11)
-Fixed bugs (squish)
Mod by Rob Tillaart - Version 0.3 (28/03/2011)
Mod by SimKard - Version 0.2 (24/11/2010)
George Hadjikyriacou - Original version (??)
#######################################################################*/


#include <dht11.h>

dht11 DHT11;

void setup()
{
    DHT11.attach(2);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("DHT11 TEST PROGRAM ");
    Serial.print("LIBRARY VERSION: ");
    Serial.println(DHT11LIB_VERSION);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("\n");

    int chk = DHT11.read();

    Serial.print("Read sensor: ");
    switch (chk)
    {
        case 0: Serial.println("OK"); break;
        case -1: Serial.println("Checksum error"); break;
        case -2: Serial.println("Time out error"); break;
        default: Serial.println("Unknown error"); break;
    }

    Serial.print("Humidity (%): ");
    Serial.println((float)DHT11.humidity, DEC);

    Serial.print("Temperature (°C): ");
    Serial.println((float)DHT11.temperature, DEC);

    Serial.print("Temperature (°F): ");
    Serial.println(DHT11.fahrenheit(), DEC);

    Serial.print("Temperature (°K): ");
    Serial.println(DHT11.kelvin(), DEC);

    Serial.print("Dew Point (°C): ");
    Serial.println(DHT11.dewPoint(), DEC);

    Serial.print("Dew PointFast (°C): ");
    Serial.println(DHT11.dewPointFast(), DEC);

    delay(2000);
}
```

And this is my ouput:

```
DHT11 TEST PROGRAM 
LIBRARY VERSION: 2S0A


Read sensor: Time out error
Humidity (%): 0.0000000000
Temperature (Â°C): 0.0000000000
Temperature (Â°F): 32.0000000000
Temperature (Â°K): 273.1499938964
Dew Point (Â°C): nan
Dew PointFast (Â°C): nan


Read sensor: Time out error
Humidity (%): 0.0000000000
Temperature (Â°C): 0.0000000000
Temperature (Â°F): 32.0000000000
Temperature (Â°K): 273.1499938964
Dew Point (Â°C): nan
Dew PointFast (Â°C): nan
```

The wiring:

-left pin: 5v

-right pin: gnd

-middle pin: 5v - digital2 - through 10kO resistor

[image]
[image]

**UPDATED:**
I found a [library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DHT11Lib) that works. I also changed the wiring because I found out the sainsmart dht11 switches the pins:

-left: signal with 10kO and to 5v

-middle: 5v

-right: GND

Now just a question.
What is the difference between these two dht11 sensors.
[Dht11 basic](http://www.exp-tech.de/Sensoren/DHT11-Feuchte-Temperatur-Sensor.html)
[dht11 with board](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-dht11-temperature-and-relative-humidity-sensor-module-for-arduino.html)

The one from sainsmart has a piece of circuit I don't know what it is.(I have a lack on electronics I try to fix step by step...)

**It is a resitor, capacitor?** it says 103.

How does this affect to the wiring?

Comment: In the code you linked, it says that you are reading pin 2 for input, but on your image, your wire is in pin 3.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You are right. It was a problem in the wiring. After fixing it I was still getting errors. The problem was the library version, that was giving some problems with read response for dht11 sensors

Answer (score 2):

The DHT11 sensor is available as-is and integrated on a break-out board. The break-out board shows following differences:

- the order of PINs is changed, e.g. in one version: 1 -> signal, 2 -> `+`, 3 -> GND (left-to-right, pins down, looking at the front)
- the unused pin is not connected
- the board already has a 10 KOhm pull-up resistor connected

Thus, when you have a DHT11 on a break-out board you have to adjust schematics that use it as-is - e.g. in this [example](https://learn.adafruit.com/dht/connecting-to-a-dhtxx-sensor) you have to remove the external pull-up resistor and connect the pins in the correct order.

Be aware that there may be different versions of DHT11 breakout boards available - i.e. ones where the order of pins is different. You can look out for PIN markings like `S` (-> signal) and `-` (-> GND). Also, you can look at both sides of the breakout board to trace the connections.

The resistor usually comes as SMD on such a board - and if it has a marking it uses a special code. For example, `103` means `10 * 10^3` Ohm, i.e. 10 KOhm.

The [adafruit DHT library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library) comes with an example sketch that prints the sensor values over serial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wiring is ok, although I think you already have pull-up resistor on breakout board (look for a small 103 resistor).

Maybe you can try another library for DHT?
I have used one made by adafruit (https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library) and everything worked just fine.

Regards,
Ian

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. I tried with and without resistor(I saw the 103 in the dht11's board). Also tried with the adafruit library and then I get the `"Failed to read from DHT sensor!"` error. I debugged the example and `readHumidity` `readTemperature` get errors on reading. Maybe my sensor is broken. I ordered a new one to check...

Comment: The DHT11 board + sensor already has the resistor. I use those with arduino directly, no extra components required.